# Our Community Ads place holder is still using the old dimensions

Tags: bug, advertising

The sidebar got [expanded to 300px](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272563/152515) the other day, so [the latest community ads](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6024/1204) look like this:

> [image: wide-ish rectangle]

But our place holder on the CDN still looks like this:

> [image: tallish rectangle]

It should become 300 × 250 too.

Comment: What's "CDN" stand for?

Comment: @nitsua60 Content Delivery Network. It's a type of service that sprung up in the past few years to serve content like images very fast across the world and reliably.

Comment: Your placeholder image does not seam to be loading for me.